# Configuring WCF/NET.TCP on IIS 7, "Unknown" next to net.tcp status?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, tcp, wcf-binding

I've tried this on two machines and can't figure it out. I've followed the instructions here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx) and ensured that the TCP listener service is running. However, next to the site application, I see "Unknown (net.tcp)" as the status.

For enabled protocols in IIS, they are listed as "http,net.tcp". My binding for net.tcp is "808:*" and the app pool is .NET 4.0 integrated. Let me know what information I can provide.

Also, when trying to connect, it says it cannot connect to the mex endpoint. My service endpoint code is below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Sandbox.ClientSideWCF.Service">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:808/service.svc" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint name="TcpEndpoint" address="" contract="Sandbox.ClientSideWCF.IService" binding="netTcpBinding" />
            <endpoint name="MetaInfo" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="netTcpBinding" address="mex" />
        </service>
    </services>
    ....
</system.ServiceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The problem was that I didn't include a service behavior. I added an empty behavior and it worked. I didn't know this was required.

Answer (score 0):

The < baseAddresses > element is for self-hosted services. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788995.aspx

Try removing it. Also see this link How to: Host a WCF Service in WAS:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx

Comment: I have followed the example in the link, however, I am using the WCF Test Client. When adding a service, I enter "net.tcp://localhost" and it returns an error saying 

"Cannot obtain Metadata from net.tcp://localhost/ ...".

I cannot figure out why I get this error and have tried looking. Thoughts? Thanks.